# Getting the total Impulse value for a collision --chipmunk spacemanager cocos2d

Tags: chipmunk

i am using spacemanager and i want to calculate the force with which the objects collide so that i can adjust the sounds and appropirate spirtes depending on the damage. can some one tell me how to calculate the forces. here is the code i got on this site.

```
if(!cpArbiterIsFirstContact(arb)) return;
```

cpFloat impulse = cpvlength(cpArbiterTotalImpulse(arb));

float volume = MIN(impulse/500.0f, 1.0f);
NSLog(@"impulse is :%f",volume);

NSLog(@" impluse x:%f y:%f", cpArbiterTotalImpulse(arb).x , cpArbiterTotalImpulse(arb).y);
  if(volume > 0.05f){
      [SimpleSound playSoundWithVolume:volume];
  }

i have this in my POSTSOLVE method.i tried it in BEGIN aswell and all it prints is 0. i went through this site and found that i needs to do this.
smgr.space->elasticIterations = smgr.space->iterations;

even after doing the above , sometimes i get 1 and some times it says "nan". is there something basic i need to know?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation for cpArbiterTotalImpulse():

> Returns the impulse that was applied
>   this step to resolve the collision.
>   These functions should only be called
>   from a postSolve() callback, otherwise
>   the result is undefined.
>
> Note: If you
>   are using the deprecated elastic
>   iterations setting on your space, it
>   will cause you to get incorrect
>   results. Elastic iterations should no
>   longer be needed, and you should be
>   able to safely turn them off.

Comment: Thank You soo much. i did this  smgr.space->elasticIterations = 0;    and its showing the impulse values now .